# How to completely remove Xmarks extension from Firefox 3.6?

Tags: firefox-extensions, xmarks

How can I remove Xmarks add-on from my Firefox 3.6 and all Xmarks profile data saved, to reinstall that later like when I installed for first time?

When I simply uninstall and reinstall it, my old profile is loaded. I tried to delete the add-on folder and some files, but when I reinstall Xmarks, my old profile is automatically loaded...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just achieved a true reinstall effect by modifying this file:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\< gibberish >.default\prefs.js
```

I deleted all the lines starting with:

```
user_pref("extensions.xmarks.
```

Probably just deleting the ones with login would be sufficient, but removing them all doesn't hurt either.

The addon actually leaves a lot more data, including in a few SQLite databases. Editing them wouldn't be that trivial I suppose but modifying prefs.js seems to be sufficient.